# Ember.js application to Firebase connection error

Tags: firebase, ember.js, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I'm new to Ember and firebase, I'm currently going through an ember tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-gd6LRt7Dcg and I'm unable to submit a form that connects to firebase. The error I'm recieving in my console is

_emberDebug.EmberError is not a constructor

My environment.js looks like this

```
contentSecurityPolicy: {
    'connect-src': "'self' wss://*.firebaseio.com"
},
firebase: {
    apiKey: 'abc',
    authDomain: 'YOUR-FIREBASE-APP.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://YOUR-FIREBASE-APP.firebaseio.com/',
    storageBucket: 'YOUR-FIREBASE-APP.appspot.com',
},
```

Ive also updated the permissions on my firebase:

```
{
 "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

On my firebase console it looks like there is no connections, so I feel like there is an issue connecting my Ember application to my database.

Comment: Is that really your environment? because it's sis just the placeholder stuff... if should have your firebase name there for `YOUR-FIREBASE-APP`... I just want to make sure that's the case before I asked anything else...  https://github.com/firebase/emberfire   - you have created a firebase on their web app, right?

Comment: That is just a placeholder for my app, and yes I have created a firebase web app